# What happens when you lose an invention that has a one-shot benefit?

Tags: robinson-crusoe

In Robinson Crusoe, the players are a collection of castaways on some remote island. There are 6 different scenarios, so the goals and perils of the game will change a bit.

During the game, you can "invent" items around camp, and various events can destroy those items. The trouble is that some items give one-shot benefits, while others give continual bonuses. For instance, the Shovel invention's benefit is "you have a shovel," which is useful because inventing the Cellar requires a shovel. On the other hand, the Spear (the Soldier's item) has a one-shot effect: +3 weapons.

What happens when an event destroys an item with a one-shot benefit? For instance, you build a Spear, get +3 weapons, use some of those weapons, and then you lose your Spear in an event when you only have 1 weapon in camp? Can you rebuild the spear again for another +3 weapons? Do you have to lose any of your existing weapons when you lose the Spear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On page 16, of the [Portal Edition rulebook](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/filepage/83030/rules-english-portal-publishing) it states that when flipping a item card over, that "If the Item had an additional effect, you should cancel it
if possible."

So if you lost, say, the Spear, you should reduce your weapon level by 3, if possible.

Earlier on the same page, it mentions the phrase "if possible", and clarifies that if you cannot pay that cost, nothing happens, and the Rule of Unfilled Demand does not apply.